# Integrating out the angular dependence of a correlation function

Tags: nuclear-physics, integration, phase-space, correlation-functions

So I have to do an integral on 2 phase spaces $d^{3}k_1$ and $d^{3}k_2$  (which at the end has to be computed numerically):

$$\iiint\!\!\!\!\iiint\!\!d^{3}k_1 d^{3}k_2~~ \frac{1}{(\vec{k}_1 - \vec{k}_2)^2 + m^2} \left (1 - \frac{\vec{k}_1\cdot\vec{k}_2}{E_1(k_1)E_2(k_2)}\right ) $$
where $E(k) = \sqrt{k^2 + m^2} $

To save computation time I was told the angular part can be done analytically to reduce this 6 dimensional integral to a 2 dimensional one. But I will have a dot product between $\vec{k}_1$ and $\vec{k}_2$ with an angle $\gamma$ between them. I tried fixing one vector and choosing it along the z-axis, so the $\gamma$ is the typical $\theta$ angle that we integrate over between 0 and $\pi$, but I'm not sure if this is correct, and if I do a change of variable with $\vec{q} = \vec{k}_1 - \vec{k}_2 $ this angle will reappear in the expression of $E(q)$.

So any tips on how to do the change of variable? Or if I can really fix one vector on the $z$-axis?

Comment: It was very clear, and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it's introductory polar geometry. Call the magnitudes of the 3-vectors $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively, and choose your $\vec k_1$ along the $\hat z$ axis. So you've done its two angular integrations to get 4π. You may do the $\phi_2$ integration to get another 2π. Since you defined $\gamma=\theta_2$, you have
$$
\cos \gamma\equiv \alpha, ~~~\leadsto \\
(\vec k_1- \vec k_2)^2= k_1^2+ k_2^2 -2k_1k_2\alpha,
$$
and
$$\iiint\!\!\!\!\iiint\!\!d^{3}k_1 d^{3}k_2~~  f(k_1, k_2,\alpha)=8\pi^2 \int_0^\infty \!\!dk_1 ~k_1^2 \int_0^\infty \!\!dk_2 ~ k_2^2 \int_{-1}^{1} \! d\alpha ~  f(k_1, k_2,\alpha). $$